# How do I perform a matches query on an integer attribute in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arel

If I have a users table with an id(integer) and I try building an sql query with arel, I get this.

```
users  = Arel::Table.new(:users)
users.where(users[:id].matches("foo")).to_sql #=> "SELECT FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` LIKE 0"
```

I need this sql generated instead:

```
"SELECT FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` LIKE 'foo'"
```

I have a feeling there's some sort of unwanted type-casting place under the hood.

**UPDATE:**

I finally solved this issue by using an instance of the Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral class.

```
str = Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral.new("'foo'")
users.where(users[:id].matches(str)).to_sql #=> "SELECT FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` LIKE 'foo'"
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you're trying to build the query on an `INT` type column. And hence, Rails tries to convert the 'foo' to an `Integer`, which is `0`.

Following will generate the expected query for the correct data type of the column:

```
users.where(users[:name].matches("foo")).to_sql #=> "SELECT FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`name` LIKE 'foo'"
```

So, in your case, you should try something like this:

```
users.where(users[:id].matches(1)).to_sql #=> "SELECT FROM `users`  WHERE `users`.`id` LIKE 1"
```

I hope it helps.